# What is it called when a prefix moved back for alphabetic sorting purposes?

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography

I have seen this many times, but I am not sure what to call this. For example, the *People's Republic of China* is often written as *China, People's Republic of*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A good question. The reason for doing it is clear enough. In the days before computers, such re-ordering of words made it easier to sort items so that alphabetical order kept similar items together. So ' trousers, grey, officers for the use of' would be listed somewhere near 'trousers, buff, other ranks for the use of', which would not happen if the first lot were 'officers' grey trousers' and the second 'other ranks' buff trousers'. I have no idea what the name for this practice might be.

Comment: I would call it _inversion_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the *Chicago Manual of Style (CMoS),* it's called an ***inversion***.

> **16.9: Main headings for index entries** 
>   …
>   A noun phrase is sometimes **inverted** to allow the keyword—the word a reader is most likely to look under—to appear first. 
>   …

```
agricultural collectivization, 143–46, 198
Aron, Raymond, 312–14
Bloomsbury group, 269
Brest-Litovsk, Treaty of, 61, 76, 85
Cold War, 396–437
Communist Party (American), 425
Communist Party (British), 268
imperialism, American, 393, 403
police, Soviet secret. See Soviet secret police
war communism, 90, 95, 125
World War I, 34–61
Yalta conference, 348, 398
```

In *CMoS's* own index, the above section appears as follows:

> index entries
>   …
>          main headings: alphabetizing, 16.56 … **inversion in, 16.9,** 16.56, 16.94; …